# Calling a php function from Javascript and using a javascript var in the php code

Tags: javascript, php, primes, prime-factoring

JavaScript

```
function calcPrimesLoop() {
    var primes = document.getElementById('primes');
    primes.appendChild(document.createTextNode('\n'+this.prime.nextPrime()));

    $.ajax({
        url: "/test.php",
        type: "post",
        data: {prime: this.prime.nextPrime()},
        success: function(data) {
        } 
    });

    calcPrimesDelay = setTimeout('calcPrimesLoop()', this.delay);
}
```

Php

```
<?php
    $content = $_POST['prime'];

    $fn = "content.txt";


    $content = stripslashes('prime'"\n");

    $fp = fopen($fn,"a+") or die ("Error opening file in write mode!");

    fputs($fp,$content);


    fclose($fp) or die ("Error closing file!");


?>
```

So this is all the relevant scripting I think. I have a script that can get prime numbers and it works perfectly. But now I want to record these numbers on a text file. This is how I am trying to do it but I am having no success at all. Thank you. The issue is the numbers aren't being recorded.

I added an alert the Ajax is working. But when I add a form to the php script and submit it that works. So the ajax and php scripts are not working together as such.

Answer (score 1):

You should read up about AJAX and see how you can pass information to a serverside page using Javascript and retrieve the return value.

http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qqRiDlm-SnY

Comment: I am not sure how ajax work? It is messing with my head. To early for this. Could you possibly explain how I would do this. Thank you :)

Comment: Just like ajax isn't at all made for internet explorer, w3schools.com isn't at all made for learning things the right way.

Comment: True, but number of webdevs grew up learning and experimenting with things on w3schools.com (especially so in the early 2000s). From the question it came across that the OP needs to understand basic clientside/serverside difference which is well illustrated here -  http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_intro.asp

Answer (score 1):

With ajax and jQuery it is actually simple.

```
function calcPrimesLoop() {
    var primes = document.getElementById('primes');
    primes.appendChild(document.createTextNode('\n'+this.prime.nextPrime()));

    $.ajax({
        url: "myScript.php",   // URL of your php script
        type: "post",
        data: {prime: this.prime.nextPrime()},
        success: function(data) {
            alert("success");
        } 
    });

    calcPrimesDelay = setTimeout('calcPrimesLoop()', this.delay);
```

}

myScript.php :

```
<?php
    $content = $_POST['prime'];
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks but this still isn't working. I have updated my code. Thank you

Comment: what is the error, is $content filled after firing ajax?

Comment: There is no error coming up. It just isn't posting the number

Answer (score 0):

You should definately look for [Asynchronous JavaScript and XML](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.ASP).

You can choose between using AJAX with a Javascript function, or simplify your life with [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Here is a sample:

```
//STEP ONE: INCLUDE THE LAST VERSION OF JQUERY
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
//STEP TWO, GET YOUR FUNCTION TO WORK:

function sendVariableTo(variable,url) {
    $.ajax({
        url:url, //Or whatever.php
        type: "GET", //OR POST
        data: { myVar: variable}, //On php page, get it like $_REQUEST['myVar'];
        success:function(result){
            //If the request was ok, then...
            alert(result) //Result variable is the php page 
            //output (If you echo "hello" this alert would give you hello..)
        },
    });
}
```

Hope this helped, bye !